# I cannot store integer in structure

Tags: c, for-loop, struct

I created a struct Book with the properties.I let the user to create the structure objects with for-loop.Like Books[i] Books1, Books2 etc...

The problem is that i cant store integer values in the structure.

The code is given below.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


struct Book {
    int ID[];
    char book_name[80];
    char author_name[50];
    int pblsh_date[];
};
struct Book *Books;

void  Create();

int main() {
    int count;
    printf("How many books do you want to enter? ");
    scanf("%d", &count);


    Create(count);

    //Show
    printf("ID\t\tName\tAuthor\tPublish Year\n");
    for (int i= 0; i < count; i++)
    printf("%d\t%s\t%s\t%d\n", Books[i].ID, Books[i].book_name, Books[i].author_name, Books[i].pblsh_date);

    if (Books) {
        free(Books);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void Create(int count) {

    Books = (struct Book*) malloc(count * sizeof(struct Book));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        printf("%d. Book's ID: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", Books[i].ID);

        printf("Book's name: ");
        scanf("%s", Books[i].book_name);

        printf("Author: ");
        scanf("%s", Books[i].author_name);

        printf("Publish Year: ");
        scanf("%d", Books[i].pblsh_date);

    }
}
```

Comment: Take square brackets away from ID and pblsh_date fields.

Comment: Thank you for your response :) I tried that at the first place but when i did it without brackets, the program crushed. http://tinyurl.com/guydtnl

Comment: It crashes in that case because of `scanf("%d", Books[i].ID);` and `scanf("%d", Books[i].pblsh_date);`. Should be `scanf("%d", &(Books[i].ID));` and `scanf("%d", &(Books[i].pblsh_date));`

Comment: Oh, that works. Thank you. Then, why is integer values require "&" symbol  but string/char dont? Thank you for your interest again :)

Answer (score 2):

The definition of the structure that you posted contains two empty arrays: `int ID[];` and `int pblsh_date[];`. Since you did not specify a size and the compiler is not throwing an error, it is not allocating any storage for the array data: the arrays are zero-length and you are overwriting the data that follows them when you `scanf` into them.

Since you only want a single integer, the correct way to define the structure is

```
struct Book {
    int ID;
    char book_name[80];
    char author_name[50];
    int pblsh_date;
};
```

The only other change you need to make to your program is the arguments to `scanf`: `scanf("%d", &(Books[i].ID));` and `scanf("%d", &(Books[i].pblsh_date));`. The reason is that `scanf` requires the address of the place you want to put the result. While `scanf("%s", Books[i].book_name);` works as is, you need to add the `&` operator to `int` variables. `book_name` is an array, which in C is treated as a pointer containing the address of the buffer you want to write to. `ID` is an int, so you need to get its address to know where to write to. Notice how you already did this in `main` with `scanf("%d", &count);`.

Comment: An array is not a pointer.  An array automatically decays into a pointer.

Comment: Just a note on "Since you did not specify a size ... it is likely not allocating any storage for the array data": it is _definietly_ not allocating any storage.

Comment: Note that the second one, `pblsh_date`, was an unintentional but valid use of a 'flexible array member' or FAM (a feature of C99 and later).  The first should have been diagnosed as a compilation error.  You can only have one FAM and it must be the last item in the structure.